# Tensorflow: OutputProjectionWrapper for Bidirectional RNNs

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Is it possible (and if so, how) to use an OutputProjectionWrapper in conjunction with a bidirectional rnn in tensorflow?  For a vanilla uni-directional RNN, the mechanism is simple:

```
cells = []

cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = 64, activation = tf.nn.tanh)  
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell1, output_keep_prob= dropout)
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell1, output_size=numOutputFeatures)

cells.append(cell1)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, source, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length = lengths)
```

Moving this to a bidirectional RNN is not obvious, though:

1. If we make a forward and backward layer, each with a projection wrapper, and use them as input to a `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`, that's obviously wrong by construction-- we want to gather the outputs of both layers together and project them all, while this does it separately.

That would look something like this:

```
cellfw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = 64, activation = tf.nn.tanh)  
cellfw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cellfw, output_keep_prob= dropout)
cellfw = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cellfw, output_size=numOutputFeatures)

cellbw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = 64, activation = tf.nn.tanh)  
cellbw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cellbw, output_keep_prob= dropout)
cellbw = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cellbw, output_size=numOutputFeatures)

outputs, state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cellfw = cellfw, cellbw = cellbw, inputs = source, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length = lengths)
```

2. The outputs of the `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` is actually a tuple (which will illustrate the wrongness of the previous approach, in fact.)  It would make sense if we could instead apply the the projection wrapper to the combined cells

However...

```
cellfw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = 64, activation = tf.nn.tanh)  
cellfw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cellfw, output_keep_prob= dropout)  
cellbw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = 64, activation = tf.nn.tanh)  
cellbw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cellbw, output_keep_prob= dropout)
```

...we can't use tf.concat here to join the cells, because cells aren't tensors.

```
outputs, state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cellfw = cellfw, cellbw = cellbw, inputs = source, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length = lengths)

outputs_fw = outputs[0]
outputs_bw = outputs[1]
outputs_combined = tf.concat([outputs_fw, outputs_bw], axis=2)
projected = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(outputs_combined, output_size=numOutputFeatures)
```

And while we can use tf.concat here, we still can't apply the projection wrapper because it requires a cell, not a tensor.

How can this be done?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?